# .Net 6 Code doesn't display in implemented large project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working in a **larger project**, but because it is very complex I made *my own small project* to make an `Azure Blobs` Gallery, that displays images from Azure Blobs using container, to implement into the large project after that.

I was able to create this [Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgsIC.png)  with the following `.Net 6` / `C#` (MVC) code:

`Controller`

```
public class ResourceController : Controller
    {
        const string blobContainerName = "thumbnails";
        static BlobContainerClient blobContainer;

        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ResourceController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = LoadModelMethodAsync();
            return View(model);
        }

        public  ActionResult Info()
        {
            var model = LoadModelMethodAsync();
            return View(model);
        }


        public  List<Uri> LoadModelMethodAsync()
        {
            try
            {

                var s = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureStorageConnectionString");

                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(s);

                blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
                 blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);
                List<Uri> allBlobs = new List<Uri>();

                foreach (BlobItem blob in blobContainer.GetBlobs())
                {
                    if (blob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.Block)
                        allBlobs.Add(blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name).Uri);
                }
                return allBlobs;
          
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewData["message"] = ex.Message;
                ViewData["trace"] = ex.StackTrace;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

`ViewModel`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace EBP_V1.ViewModels {

public class ResourceViewModel
{
    public string RequestId { get; set; }

    public bool? ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
}
}
```

`Partial`

```
@using AzureBlobLearning.Models

@model List<Uri>

@{

}
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="imageBlock" value="GetGallery">
            <a href="@item" target="_blank"><img class="thumb" src="@item" alt="images"/></a><br />
            <div class="deleteDiv"><img class="deleteIcon" src="~/Images/deleteImage.png" title="Delete Image" onclick="deleteImage('@item');" /></div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

`View: Info.cshtml`

```
<partial name="~/Views/Resource/_ResourcePartial.cshtml"/>
```

This *small project* works well, but when I try to implement it in the **large project**, [the page isn't working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnGBa.png) anymore, even though it doesn't throw any error, and when I try to debug it all the data the same as it was before.

`Controller in the large project ( everything else is identical with the previous one)`

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ViewResult> Info(Guid? id, string filterTxt )
{
    await SetCompanyName(id, filterTxt);
    var model = LoadModelMethodAsync();
    return View(model);
}
```

The interesting thing is that even if I don't call the `model` variable in the View the page still won't work anymore.

Question:

- Why my code doesn't work in the **large project**?
- What should I change to make it work?

*P.S.:*

*- I am a completely beginner in `.Net 6 / C#` world, my first language
is Javascript, so please be understanding.*
*- If you have any    questions, suggestions don't hesitate to ask.*

Comment: 500 means that there was unhandled exception on server side. For us to help you you will need to at least provide it for us.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you think what I have to provide for you?

Comment: Try running in debug mode and make sure your IDE is configured to break on unhandled exceptions.